# Does MUI v5 provides example of theme or styles that they are using for their home page?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles

MUI team have very attractive example in their homepage

[image]

And I want to know does they provide some of examples what styling or theme that they are using? Do they have some codesandbox something? I tried a lot of example but always show default material style!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MUI is an open source project, including its docs website. You can see the project on Github [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/pages). The components in the landing page are customized in [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.1.0/docs/src/modules/brandingTheme.ts) file.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the MUI theme object directly in the mui.com console

[image]